# Cannot connect Planetscale DB (Prisma Error: P1001)

Tags: prisma, planetscale

Im trying to push to Planetscale using Prisma, but keep getting the next error:

Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `aws.connect.psdb.cloud`:`3306`

Please make sure your database server is running at `aws.connect.psdb.cloud`:`3306`.

I setup everything as I did many times before, but now I cant find any error.
Any solution?

Used npx prisma generate to check if its working, generated successfully. Then used npx prisma db push and got the error.

Comment: Are you able to connect to your database through a database IDE like TablePlus or DataGrip?

Comment: This is not about programming, it rather belongs to serverfault.com.